# how can I reload/refresh properties in spring at runtime without jvm restart?

Tags: java, spring, refresh, reload, applicationcontext

how can I reload/refresh properties in spring at runtime without jvm restart?

I am looking for something elegant and it should be applicable in Prod. Therefore, JRebel is off the table I guess.

Currently, I have my properties in MYProject.properties

```
oms.url=abbc.com
checkin.enabled=true
```

and my java file is autowired to search and use these properties from applicationContext provided different property files:

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="myproject.config.CustomPropertyPlaceHolder">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:MyProject.properties</value>
                <value>file:${CATALINA_BASE}/lib/MyProject.properties</value>
                <!--<value>file:///appl/conf/outlet.properties</value>-->
                <value>classpath:db.password</value>
                <value>file:${CATALINA_BASE}/lib/db.password</value>
                <!-- <ref bean="applPropertiesFromDb" /> -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and Java file as:

```
@Value("${checkin.enabled}")
    private String checkinEnabled;
```

Comment: As far as I know Spring properties resolve to java final static variables so they cannot be changed once instantiated without a jvm restart.

Comment: Its not exactly spring property, but more of a Bean which container initialises on startup.

Comment: Depends on the nature of the bean. If it is like in your example, and  it initializes the connection to DB, even if the bean gets reconfigured then what happens to the old connection? Internally, Spring beans have a lifecycle, that could be restarted, can hardly tell that it is possible without sever intrusion into the framework code. Maybe look for some JMX capabilities instead?

Comment: @AntonArhipov: Yes I looked into JMX option too. But the limitation am facing is, with JMX I will have to load all properties by hand and I loose the use of annotations:

Comment: @AshishGarg Ah, yes. With annotations you have almost no chances, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

But this will not be refreshed.

```
private String checkinEnabled;
```

You must reload `checkinEnabled` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing MessageSource Spring bean like this:
1.Update applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.mycompany.service.DynamicMessageSource" />
```

2.Write your own MessageSource implementation

```
public class DynamicMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {

    // Autowire propertiesService

    @Override
    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
        String result = propertiesService.getProperty(code);
        return new MessageFormat(result, locale);
    }
}
```

3.Implement your custom service to read properties from some place (DB, properties file, etc).
4.Enjoy dynamic updates of properties when updating the properties source.